# Overwriting ant.d's menu item's underline styling

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

So I'm using ant.design to create my navbar. Initially, ant's menu items have a underline when either selected or hovered upon (this underline is a blue-ish border-bottom). I now want to change this underline's color to suit the rest of my design. I managed to change the bar's color when selected by targeting a specific class like this:

```css
&& .ant-menu-item-selected::after{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #659e38 !important;
}
```

However, I want the color changed also when hovered upon, but when I target the menu item like this:

```css
  && .ant-menu-item:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #659e38 !important;
  }
```

I get a undesired result of:
[image]

How can I get what I want? Note that I'm using styled.components for styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change:

```css
&& .ant-menu-item:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #659e38 !important;
  }
```

to:

```css
&& .ant-menu-item:hover::after{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #659e38 !important;
  }
```

this is (I believe) due to bar's being created as a pseudoelement by ant.d.

Answer (score 0):

The solution using styled component:

```js
import { Menu as BaseMenu } from 'antd';

export const Menu = styled(BaseMenu)`
  // add our style
  .ant-menu-item-selected {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ff5722 !important;
    color: #ff5722 !important;
  }

  & .ant-menu-item:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d9d9d9 !important;
    color: black !important;
  }

  // remove ant design blue border
  .ant-menu-item-selected::after {
    content: none;
    border-bottom: none !important;
  }

  & .ant-menu-item:hover::after {
    content: none;
    border-bottom: none !important;
  }
`;
```