# Customize ant.design menu

Tags: menu, antd, customization, react-typescript

I'm doing first steps in frontend developing: react, typescript, ant.design, menu.

Could you suggest can I remove this blue line that is underlying the menu item (see the picture below).
I would like to highlight the menu items like "File" itself.

[image]

Since, I'm new in frontend plese, explain with detail.

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI. hope that help your problem - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487638/overwriting-ant-ds-menu-items-underline-styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73487638/overwriting-ant-ds-menu-items-underline-styling)